# How can I make my iOS app handle a specific domain?

Tags: ios, configuration

I want to register my application to handle a specific domain, for example:

`http://mycompany.com` would open my application if it is installed on the device. Is this possible? I know that I can register a url scheme, like `mycompany://`, but I want to be able to  handle a standard url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this unfortunately, iOS only lets 3rd party apps register to handle custom URL schemes, not domains.

The mechanism whereby different apps intercept youtube, maps, iTunes URLs, etc. is private to Apple's own applications.

Comment: Would it be possible to detect whether the application is installed via javascript/ajax? I mean something like: user clicks link to web page, detect user agent, check if the application is installed, if so, redirect to the custom url scheme, which would trigger the app to open? This seems like it would work, but before I tried it I figured I could ask.